# how to create onclick button which will paste data to textfield

Tags: android, button, paste

I want to create a button in my app the will PASTE data from clipdata to the focused text field. How can I make a onClick paste button?

thanks

Comment: too complex question. Split it into several. 1. how to get clipboard data. 2. how to set text to text field (BTW, what is text field? there is no such class in Android SDK). 3. how to do something on button click. 4. how to get active text field.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick(View view){
    String text = ...;    //get text from clipboard.
    textView.setText(text);
}
```